# Snakepit - Version collisions with Pygame install on Python 3.4.2

Tags: pygame, python-3.4

I'm unable to get Pygame to install in my python3.4.2 installation and I don't know why.  I suspect it may be due to having 3 different Python versions on my 64bit Win7 desktop.

So my main question is:  How do I tell Pygame (or pip) to install PyGame in Python 3.4.2 instead of Anaconda's 3.4.1

My 2nd question would be how to make iPython (Anaconda) use 3.4.2 from the Python34 directory instead of Anaconda's distro?

The error I'm getting is this, which seems to indicate it is trying to install in the Anaconda directory instead of Python34 directory
Here are the contents of my pip.log file after the install:

```
   C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 05/28/15 15:09:06
   Unpacking c:\python34\scripts\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
   Installing collected packages: pygame
   Cleaning up...
   Exception:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in run
        requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1435, in install
        requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 671, in install
        self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
        pycompile=self.pycompile,
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
        clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 209, in clobber
        shutil.copy2(srcfile, destfile)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 244, in copy2
        copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 108, in copyfile
        with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pygame\\base.pyd'
```

This is my PATH variable:

[image]

I 3 different Python installs:

- Python 3.4.2  in C:\Python34
- Python 3.4.1  in C:\Anaconda  (so I can
  run iPython)
- Python 2.7.8  in C:\Python27

I downloaded pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl 
copied it to C:\Python34\Scripts
opened Windows PowerShell
navigated to C:\Python34\Scripts
ran the command

pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

This produced the following output:

```
Unpacking c:\python34\scripts\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.
Installing collected packages: pygame
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1435, in
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 671, in
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 901, in
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 215, i
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 209, i
    shutil.copy2(srcfile, destfile)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 244, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 108, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Anaconda3\\Li

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Les Paul\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: `PS C:\Python34\Scripts> .\pip3.4 install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`  also gives me an error, starting with  
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)` and ending with 
  `File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ndg\httpsclient\ssl_peer_verification.py", line 17
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`